# Jquery .post: Are dynamic names (from name/value pairs) possible?

Tags: jquery

```
      $('form#input, form#radio, form#select').change(function() {
    $.post("assets/ajax/save.php",
          { "id": $("input#id").val(), $(this).attr('name') : $(this).val() },
          function(data) {
            alert(data);
          },
          "html"
        );
});
```

*The bit in question is the "$(this).attr('name')" portion. Is it possible to dynamically create the name? The above code throws an error.*

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is, but you have to use bracket (`[]`) notation to build the hash:

```
  $('form#input, form#radio, form#select').change(function() {
    var data = {"id": $("input#id").val()};
    data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    $.post("assets/ajax/save.php",
      data,
      function(data) {
        alert(data);
      },
      "html"
    );
  });
```